# Trigger click of element with selected css value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some divs with same class please see this

```
<div class="parent" style="display:none">
        <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(198, 172, 0);">hii</div>
        <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(134, 122, 36);">hii</div>
        <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(251, 206, 146);">hii</div>
        <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(249, 70, 28);;">hii</div>
</div>

<div class="div2">text</div>
```

How to perform trigger click for `class-1` which style colour is `rgb(134, 122, 36)`?

Comment: how can you click when the div is hidden?

Comment: there are other jquery and other html part . I just written the basic for what i need .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jQuery's [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) with the help of the jQuery [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```js
$(".class-1[style='color:rgb(198, 172, 0);']").on('click', function(){
 alert('works');
});

$(".class-1[style='color:rgb(198, 172, 0);']").trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" style="display:none">
        <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(198, 172, 0);">hii</div>
        <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(134, 122, 36);">hii</div>
        <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(251, 206, 146);">hii</div>
        <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(249, 70, 28);;">hii</div>
</div>

<div class="div2">text</div>
```

Comment: could you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276905/processing-backwardundo-and-forwardredo-option-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the elements with a given class and then compare their css color attribute and trigger a click if it matches your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.class-1').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).css('color'));
  })
  $('.class-1').each(function(index, item) {
    console.log($(item).css('color') == 'rgb(134, 122, 36)');
    if($(item).css('color') == 'rgb(134, 122, 36)') {
      $(item).trigger("click");
    }
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" >
    <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(198, 172, 0);">hii</div>
    <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(134, 122, 36);">hii</div>
    <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(251, 206, 146);">hii</div>
    <div class="class-1" style="color:rgb(249, 70, 28);;">hii</div>

</div>

<div class="div2">text</div>
```

Comment: There is not much difference, you can just change the color attribute value to test.

Comment: could you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276905/processing-backwardundo-and-forwardredo-option-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You also can do something like this.

```
$(function(){
    $(".class-1[style='color:rgb(134, 122, 36);']").on('click', function(){
        alert('red');
    });

    $('.class-1').each(function (i, el) {
        if($(el).attr('style') == 'color:rgb(134, 122, 36);') {
        $(el).trigger('click')
      }
    })
})
```

Comment: could you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276905/processing-backwardundo-and-forwardredo-option-using-jquery